# Table view data display in specific format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my table view i want to show some headers in that in ios so what can i do for this to achieve that . my code is given below...cos i want to display the data like .....
Name     Class     RollNo    Address
in table view Then what to do for this.. Anyone can help me out????

```
enter code here
    deliveryCases = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 320, 480)];
     deliveryCases.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     deliveryCases.dataSource = self;
     deliveryCases.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:deliveryCases];

  UIView *headerView0 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100 , 50)];
     UILabel *labelView0 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100 , 50)];
    labelView0.text = @"Name";
  [headerView0 addSubview:labelView0];
  deliveryCases.tableHeaderView = headerView0;


    UIView *headerView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 19, 100 , 50)];
   UILabel *labelView1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 19, 100 , 50)];
 labelView1.text = @"CLass";
  [headerView1 addSubview:labelView1];
 deliveryCases.tableHeaderView = headerView1;
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [deliveryCases     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}

      [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     tableView.allowsSelection=YES;

       return cell;



  }

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    return 1;
  }   

    -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
     return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is right, adding a View in your Header. With correct origin of all the Labels, you'll achieve what you want.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:VIEW_FRAME_HERE];


    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:LABEL_FRAME_HERE];
    lbl1.text = @"YOUR_HEADER_NAME";
    [headerView addSubview:lbl1];

    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:LABEL_FRAME_HERE];
    lbl2.text = @"YOUR_HEADER_NAME";
    [headerView addSubview:lbl2];
    .
    .
    .
    return headerView;
}
```

So, in your TableViewCell, you just add a subview to it with correct origin of Labels and its values. It would be proper if you Subclass the UITableViewCell and add the subviews there.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *myCell = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myCell];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myCell];
    }

    UIView *cellValues = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CELL_FRAME_HERE];


    UILabel *value1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:VALUE_FRAME_HERE];
    value1.text = @"VALUES_HERE";
    [cellValues addSubview:value1];

    UILabel *value2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:VALUE_FRAME_HERE];
    value2.text = @"VALUES_HERE";
    [cellValues addSubview:value2];
    .
    .
    .
    [cell addSubview:cellValues];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: yes, just like what you did in adding labels in your cell, just add UITextField in your cell... And if you want to determine a specific fields, put tags in your fields and access them by their tags